# count_bases return as dictionary

Tags: python

So I was wondering if anybody wants to help me with this. I don't even understand where to begin? Any help would be appreciated.

Write a function called `count_bases` that counts the number of times each letter occurs in a given string. The results should be returned as a dictionary, with letters in upper case as keys and the number of occurrences as (integer) values

For example when the function is called with the string 'ATGATAGG', it should return `{'A': 3, 'T': 2, 'G': 3, 'C': 0}`. Please ensure your function uses return, not print(). The order of the keys in the dictionary does not need to follow this order (2 marks).

Make sure that your function works when passed any lower and/or uppercase DNA characters in the sequence string. (2 marks)

DNA sequences sometimes contain letters other than A, C, G to T to indicate degenerate nucleotides. For example, R can represent A or G (the purine bases). If the program encounters any letter other than A, C, G or T, it should also count the frequency of that letter and return within the dictionary object. (2 marks).

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
def count_bases(input_str):
    result = {}
    for s in input_str:
        try:
            result[s]+=1
        except:
            result[s] = 1

    return result

print(count_bases('ATGATAGG'))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 3, 'T': 2, 'G': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
def f(input):
  d = {}
  for s in input:
    d[s] = d.get(s,0)+1
  return d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def count_bases(sequence):
    # since you want to count both lower and upper case letters,
    # it'd be better if you convert the input sequence to either upper or lower.
    sequence = sequence.upper()
    # Counter (from collections) does the counting for you. It takes list as input. 
    # So, list(sequence) will separate letters from your sequence into a list of letters ('abc' => ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    # It returns you a Counter object. Since you want a dictionary, cast it to dict.
    return dict(Counter(list(sequence)))
```

> count_bases('ATGATAGGaatdga')
>
> {'A': 6, 'T': 3, 'G': 4, 'D': 1}

Comment: Not likely to make sense to someone who has "no idea how to begin".  OP would have to know that `Counter` is a class in the `collections` package.